# Need help on JS callback hell

Tags: javascript, callback, es6-promise

I am challenging myself by writing a simple JavaScript callback hell to grasp the concept without using the widely spread setTimeout function examples on the net.
I did something wrong and haven't succeeded yet to nest my callbacks and return the final result.

```js
const multiplication = (a, b) => {
  let multiply = a * b;
  console.log(`${multiply} from multiplication`);
  return multiply;
};
const addition = (multiply, n1) => {
  let add = multiply + n1;
  console.log(`${add} from addition`);
  return division(add);
};
const division = (add) => {
  let div = add / 2;
  console.log(`${div} from division`);
  return div;
};

console.log(
  multiplication(10, 20, () => {
    addition(multiply, 100, () => {
      division(add);
    });
  })
);
```

Comment: This code isn't making much sense at all.  Your `multiplaction()` function expects two arguments, NOT three and when called, it doesn't call a callback so the code  you show is simply wrong.  Same with your other functions.  ***None*** of them accept a callback.  These functions are not asynchronous so they should not be using callbacks at all.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I know the code doesn't make sense, i am new to programming in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use callbacks, then you'll have to define them as arguments to your functions, and also to call them at the end instead of `return`ing.

Due to how callback control flow works, you won't be able to do

```
console.log(
  multiplication(10, 20, () => {
    ...
```

Rather, you'll have to log in the innermost defined callback to get to the final result.

```js
const multiplication = (a, b, callback) => {
  let multiply = a * b;
  console.log(`${multiply} from multiplication`);
  callback(multiply);
};
const addition = (multiplyResult, n1, callback) => {
  let add = multiplyResult + n1;
  console.log(`${add} from addition`);
  callback(add);
};
const division = (add, callback) => {
  let div = add / 2;
  console.log(`${div} from division`);
  callback(div);
};

multiplication(10, 20, (multiplyResult) => {
  addition(multiplyResult, 100, (addResult) => {
    division(addResult, (divisionResult) => {
      console.log('innermost', divisionResult);
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks Sir That's what am looking for hope i can follow and deeply understand the code ^^